# How to restrict number of characters on a single line?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText to generate PDFs. In these PDFs, I need to add two `String`s on one line.

The first `String` (`string1`) length is between 1 and 10. The length of the second `String` (`string2`) is unknown, but the combined length of `string1` and `string2` should not exceed 10 characters.

How can I add these strings to a single line that is underlined?

Comment: my pdf form format is static but some values in some places I will add dynamic values

Comment: for example in PDF ,

Comment: First Name:Rajkumar    Last Name: Ch     in the give data First Name and Last Name are static values in the pdf , Rajkumar and Ch are dynamic

Comment: The question is indeed unclear. For insance "If `String2` is having only 5 or 10 characters, the remaining 85 or 80 characters should be spaces." Why? The concept of spaces in PDF is special. In PDF, text is added at absolute positions. Spaces may not be necessary. Also: why don't you just check `string1.length() + string2.length()`? Why is this a PDF question? This question should be rephrased.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Bruno, In my case I am generating challans  which contains some dynamic values, and as you said I have added String1.length()+string2.length(),But as per requirement I need to add spaces after adding string2 value

Comment: And I will have multiple  Phrases with these string1+string2 in my document,Each phrase should end at the same end point of the line to achive this I am adding spaces

Comment: Exactly I am looking for , I want to print the phrase with limited number of characters including spaces in a line.    Please help me out of this

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the [UnderlineParagraphWithTwoParts](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/UnderlineParagraphWithTwoParts) example and allow me to explain which problems are solved in this example.

**First problem:** you want to make sure that 100 characters fit on one line. I've made this 101 characters because I assume that you want some space between `string1` and `string2` (if not, it should be easy to adapt the example).

As you don't know the content of `string1` and `string2` in advance, I've chosen a font of which all the glyphs have the same width: Courier (this is a *fixed width* or *monospaced* font). If you want to use a proportional font (such as Arial), you will have a very hard time calculating the font size, in the sense that you will have to calculate the font size separately for every `string1` and `string2` combination. This will result in a very odd-looking document where each line has a different font size.

This is the code to calculate the font size, based on the width of a single character in the font `COURIER`, the fact that we want to add 101 characters on one line that has a width equal to the space available between the right and left margin of the page:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
float charWidth = bf.getWidth(" ");
int charactersPerLine = 101;
float pageWidth = document.right() - document.left();
float fontSize = (1000 * (pageWidth / (charWidth * charactersPerLine)));
fontSize = ((int)(fontSize * 100)) / 100f;
Font font = new Font(bf, fontSize);
```

Note that I round the value of the float. If you don't do this, you may experience problems due to rounding errors inherent to using `float` values.

**Problem2:** Now we want to add two string to a single line and underline them. From your question, it isn't clear how you want to align these strings.

This is the simple situation, where `string1` and `string2` are separated by a single space:

```
public void addParagraphWithTwoParts2(Document document, Font font, String string1, String string2)
        throws DocumentException {
    if (string1 == null) string1 = "";
    if (string1.length() > 10)
        string1 = string1.substring(0, 10);
    if (string2 == null) string2 = "";
    if (string1.length() + string2.length() > 100)
        string2 = string2.substring(0, 100 - string1.length());
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(string1 + " " + string2, font);
    LineSeparator line = new LineSeparator();
    line.setOffset(-2);
    p.add(line);
    document.add(p);
}
```

This is a more complex situation, where you right-align `string2`:

```
public void addParagraphWithTwoParts1(Document document, Font font, String string1, String string2)
        throws DocumentException {
    if (string1 == null) string1 = "";
    if (string1.length() > 10)
        string1 = string1.substring(0, 10);
    Chunk chunk1 = new Chunk(string1, font);
    if (string2 == null) string2 = "";
    if (string1.length() + string2.length() > 100)
        string2 = string2.substring(0, 100 - string1.length());
    Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk(string2, font);
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
    p.add(chunk1);
    p.add(GLUE);
    p.add(chunk2);
    LineSeparator line = new LineSeparator();
    line.setOffset(-2);
    p.add(line);
    document.add(p);
}
```

As you can see, we do not have to add any spaces, we just use a `GLUE` chunk that is defined like this:

```
public static final Chunk GLUE = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
```

I've created an example where `string1` and `string2` consist of numbers. This is what the result looks like:

[image: Screen shot]

In this screen shot, you see examples where `string2` is right aligned as well as examples where `string2` is added right after `string1` (but separated from it with a single space character).

Comment: First of all Thanks Bruno and I am very sorry for confusing you, My requirement is like in the screen shot of the last row you provided.

Comment: In that case, you have your answer: you need to use the `addParagraphWithTwoParts2()` method I wrote. The result of my Proof-of-Concept can be found here: http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/underline_paragraph_with_two_parts.pdf As I already explained: no extra spaces need to be added at the end of `string2`!

Comment: Thank you lowagie! It is working.Now we are using addParagraphWithTwoParts2(document,font,string1,string2),I want to know Is there any possibility to use the above function with Pragraph or phrase i.e addParagraphWithTwoParts2(Paragraph/Phrase,font,string1,string2).Please let me know!

Comment: You are no longer passing a `document` object as a parameter, only a `Paragraph` (or a `Phrase`). This is very odd. I don't understand the question. I am pretty sure that your question is wrong.

Comment: Actually in the above method we are passing document object , I am asking for can we pass paragraph or phrase object in same method with same number of parameters,Because my PDF contains lot of paragraphs and phrases and tables, I am adding all the Paragraphs and Tables objects to documents object at the end of the coding before closing the document i.e, before document.close().

Comment: Passing a `Paragraph` doesn't make sense because it costs more CPU time. You would have to get the `Chunk`s from the `Paragraph`, measure the widths and then create new `Paragraphs` (and implicitly new `Chunk`s). I also reject your argument: you say your PDF contains a lot of paragraphs. So what? Those paragraphs were originally `String`s, weren't they?